# Why does PC turn on but nothing happens on screen?

Tags: boot, display, desktop-computer

Like the title, my PC turns on (green light on power button) but nothing happens on the screen (yellow light on the power button). I test the screen with the same cables on another PC and it works. My PC has both integrated and dedicated graphic cards; I plug in both yet neither works.

Can you give some hint as where to diagnose and fix?

EDIT: There is no beep when turning it on, if that may mean something.

EDIT 2: I tried a few tricks based on suggestions here, including removing the dedicated graphic card and adjusting the screen configurations. None of those worked though.

Comment: Try removing the dedicated graphics from your machine entirely and see if you get output with the integrated afterwards.  If so, I would recommend trying to install drivers for the card in advance.  Let me know what happens.  **Also**, do you hear "Beeps" or checks when you turn the machine on?

Comment: @CheesusCrust Thanks for your suggestion, I'll try. There is no beep. Does it mean something for the check?

Comment: Beeps can mean a number of things, usually the BIOS checks when it goes through its POST diagnostics.  No beeps could possibly be a sign that it is not going through these diagnostics, which could point that something is holding it up.  Although, **beep codes** vary between machines.  I was asking as more of a curiosity.  Go ahead and try what I mentioned before and report the result.

Comment: @CheesusCrust I removed the dedicated graphic card but still it didn't work. Before it got into this problem I used the integrated graphic card, just to say that the integrated card had worked OK then.

Comment: There's definitely something more serious going on, if it's a bad setting/driver or any software thing, it should at least show something when just after turn on, because BIOS POST screen is not affected by anything like OS level or higher.

Comment: Did you try "minimal system" method? Leave only Mobo+CPU+RAM+PSU inside, and only connect power+monitor outside, see if it show something?

Answer (score 0):

As Sam mentioned. Try a minimal setup.

1. Just Mobo,RAM,PSU, and CPU. No USB devices or HDDs plugged in.
2. Make sure the monitor is on the correct input and turned on.
3. Look for error light codes. Beep codes aren't the only way computer manufacturers distinguish errors. Sometimes you'll have to look for the USB lights on the front. Or the HDD light. And your computer owners manual will tell you what light codes mean for your specific computer.
4. You can try taking out one stick of RAM at a time to see if it's one of them. (I know there is usually a beep if  it's the RAM, but something could've happened to the speaker on the Mobo or really anything else)
5. Is the CPU fan spinning? Or does it start to spin then stop? Cause that could be an indication of some hardware failure, like not enough power, bad ram, bad CPU, etc. Just any sort of hardware problem and the computer realizes it.
6. Is there any damage to the video out ports? Or any ports in general?

As Sam also said, at very least you should get the BIOS splash screen and a POST message. But if those aren't showing then it's probably hardware error, or something not connected right.